# Pure JavaScript: toggle links active

Tags: javascript

My code is working only for first "a" child. Does not working on the rest "a" child. Why?

There are some solutions on the internet but in jQuery. I prefer pure JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', active);

function active() {
    document.querySelector('a').classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated but.. "I prefer pure JavaScript", *why?*

Comment: Cause `document.querySelector('a')` only returns the *first found element*

Answer (score 1):

Add id instead of class; remove 'active' class on each click and then add 'active' class to clicked anchor tag;

```js
document.getElementById('news').onclick = active;
document.getElementById('home').onclick = active;
document.getElementById('contact').onclick = active;
document.getElementById('about').onclick = active;

//addEventListener('click', active);

function active() {
    document.querySelector('a.active').classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" id="home" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news" id="news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact" id="contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about" id="about">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation with `querySelectorAll` to write small and neat solution like below:

```js
document.querySelector('.topnav').addEventListener('click', active);

function active(e) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.topnav > a').forEach(function(a){
      a.classList.remove('active');
    })
    e.target.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
  .topnav {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: grey;
    }

    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .topnav a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    .topnav a.active {
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
  
    <div class="topnav">
      <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need *querySelectorAll* and some looping:

```
const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('a');

menuItems.forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', active)
);

function active() {
  menuItems.forEach(el =>
    el.classList.remove('active')
  );
  this.classList.add('active');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.querySelectorAll('a')`